# To create an update routine with DBeaver

Tags: database, dbeaver

I need to create a weekly update routine using a script or any other method that works. I am using DBeaver/Greenplum, and I need to automate the process to download only the updated part of the database, not the entire database. I am working with a database of up to 29 million rows, so it is essential that only the updated portion is downloaded.

I have no experience in this database area, and I am having difficulty finding relevant material on the internet regarding this matter.

I tried using simple SQL scripts, but none had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I suggest to you use "PostgreSQL CLI" (psql), instead of "DBeaver".
I may download here, https://www.postgresql.org/download/.

After that, you can use SQL command line in prompt, e.g.:

```
psql -h localhost -c 'select version()'
```

For download the result set:

```
psql -h localhost -c 'select version()' -o result.txt
```

For automation and schedule, you can use '[task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)' if you using Windows plataform or '[cron](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crontab-in-linux-with-examples/)' if you using linux plataform.